# Glitchy ng-animate fade on ng-show/ng-hide

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate, ng-show, ng-hide

So I have a set of cards that after five seconds fade from a loading cog to some dummy information. I'm using ng-show and ng-hide to move the cog to the info. My issue is that as the fade happens there is a moment of everything on the page. I've never really used ng-animate before so I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. Below are links to my github repo for this and the github demo. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

[Github Repo](https://github.com/alexmarple/quantcast)

[Github Demo](https://alexmarple.github.io/quantcast/)

Comment: I hate Angular. I would use VueJS instead. It's a lot like angular, but it's a lot like backbone, and you can use it with Jquery, and perform inline expressions. It's also about 10x faster than Angular and about 2x faster than React. With Webpack it's about 10x faster than react. I can completely render any kind of page within 500ms. You can also use VueJS with Angular if you feel like you are too deep in to refactor.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the answer was in positioning everything absolutely so there wasn't any momentary glitchiness.